# AngularFire cordova Oauth not functioning

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

So I am building an ionic app with angularfire auth but $signInWithRedirect and $signInWithPopUp won't work because of the environment http/https thing so I added the `cordovaOauth` plugin and my code looks like this:

```
  $cordovaOauth.facebook("app_id", ["email"]).then(function (result) {
  alert(result.access_token); //i get this alert
    Auth.$signInWithCredentials(result.access_token).then(function (firebaseUser) {
      alert('success'); 
      alert(firebaseUser);
      $scope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser;
    }, function (error) {
      alert(error);
    });
  }, function (error) {
    alert(error);
  });
```

When I run this I get the alert `result.access_token` though I'm not going to the next alerts meaning I have a problem with my `$signInWithCredentials`.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$signInWithCredentials should be $signInWithCredential
You also have to wrap the access token in a credential object:
$signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.access_token));